Is there any way to speed up simulation in Ltspice?
The following is my FM transmitter circuit. It takes about 1 minute to simulate.

In real life, I want to use this BFQ19SH6327XTSA1 from Infineon instead of 2N22222. (link datasheet) and download link for lib
***************************************************************
*   Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   GUMMEL-POON MODEL   IN  SPICE   2G6 SYNTAX
*   VALID   UP  TO  6   GHZ
*   >>> BFQ19S  <<<
*   (C) 2014    Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   Version 2.1 October 2014
***************************************************************
*.OPTION TNOM=25, GMIN= 1.00e-12
*BFQ19S C B E
.SUBCKT BFQ19S 11 22 33
*
CBEPAR 2 3 1.941E-014
CBCPAR 2 1 5.476E-013
CCEPAR 1 3 7.843E-013
LB    2 20 2.448E-009
LE   3 30 1.706E-009
Rci 1 10 0.002258
CBEPCK 20 30  8.568E-016
CBCPCK 10 20  1.201E-014
CCEPCK 10 30  8.448E-014
LBX    20 22 7.525E-013
LEX   30 33 1.178E-010
LCX   10 11  2.449E-010
*
*
Q1 1 2 3 M_BFQ19S
*
*
.MODEL  M_BFQ19S    NPN(
+   TNOM    =   25
+   IS  =   1.734E-015
+   BF  =   126.2
+   NF  =   0.9968
+   VAF =   52.15
+   IKF =   1.035
+   ISE =   7.715E-015
+   NE  =   1.81
+   BR  =   13.1
+   NR  =   0.9968
+   VAR =   3.079
+   IKR =   0.1214
+   ISC =   6.257E-015
+   NC  =   1.6
+   RB  =   5.552
+   IRB =   2.4E-005
+   RBM =   1.524
+   RE  =   0.2261
+   RC  =   1.814
+   XTB =   0.854
+   EG  =   1.11
+   XTI =   9.516
+   CJE =   4.551E-012
+   VJE =   0.7397
+   MJE =   0.3271
+   TF  =   2.467E-011
+   XTF =   4.69
+   VTF =   6.79
+   ITF =   1.027
+   PTF =   9.546E-017
+   CJC =   1.164E-012
+   VJC =   0.6791
+   MJC =   0.3983
+   XCJC    =   0.007944
+   TR  =   3.412E-008
+   CJS =   0
+   VJS =   0.3601
+   MJS =   0.02997
+   FC  =   0.567
+   KF  =   2.2E-14
+   AF  =   1.6)
***************************************************************
*
*
.ENDS BFQ19S


what is your definition of ages?  ... how is anyone to know if the circuit simulates faster on their computer?

@jsotola It took around 1 mins to simulate on ,my laptop

how is "1 minute" ages??? That makes no sense. You're simulating a complex circuit with nonlinear elements for a prolonged time, and necessarily at a time resolution that allows you to resolve 100 MHz. So, your question here has nothing to do with the circuit.

I have some simulations that run for 30 minutes. The trick is not to use "probes" but rather use a formal transient analysis that lists the nodes you want to see waveforms for. Then, no matter how long it takes to finish a "run" you see the waveforms evolving and can cut short things if not satisfactory. It makes a big difference. If I could persuade everyone using a simulator to ditch clicking on nodes to see waveforms, life would become easier for them.

@MarcusMüller Well, I changed the question. I am wondering how to make this oscillate  using BFQ19SH6327XTSA1

But you already got an answer to your original question! It is considered bad form to change the content of the question after answers have been given

I rolled back the question so it matches the (very good) answer below. Please don’t change questions like this. Make a new one if the scope changes that drastically.

For a 'stiff' circuit (meaning there are multiple widely differing timescales which are important), a transient (.TRAN) analysis will always take a long time.
Basically the circuit (simulator) has to take timesteps small enough to properly model the carrier frequency (say 100 MHz), while also running long enough for your modulation to progress through a few cycles. So slow signals (modulation) spend long 'boring' intervals generating 100 MHz cycles.
Your modulation is AC-coupled to the carrier generator. Since the modulation dynamics are not critical in this circuit, you can determine the modulation depth by using DC signals.
This is one way:
You can DC-couple it (at least for simulation) by removing C1, and apply a (variable) DC signal in series with R6. This represents the modulation signal.
Run a .OP simulation, and measure the voltages at each end of C2. Replace C2 with a voltage source equal to the differences in these voltages (this effectively replaces C2 with an infinite capacitance).
Now run a .TRAN for a small number of carriers cycles (say 10-20), and repeat for different DC input levels. If this DC represents the amplitude of your modulation, you will know the FM deviation achievable. If it was critical, you could analyze the resultant carrier frequency vs. DC input and determine modulation linearity.
Another technique (not available in LTSPICE) is Periodic Steady State (PSS) which simulates by using the fact that the signal is periodic (either the carrier, or the modulation if it is harmonically related), and finding the final 'steady state' behaviour. However when there is a large ratio between modulation and carrier frequencies, this is not much better than a .TRAN.

How can I make this circuit oscillate in FM frequency?
